# Prediction Model for Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence

Consider the following example dataset with 1-minute timestamps and 5 numerical columns:

Example dataset:

```
Timestamp            Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Column 4   Column 5   Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-06-20 09:30:00  10.5       50         0.75       100        8.2         NaN
2023-06-20 09:31:00  11.2       45         0.80       98         8.6         lower
2023-06-20 09:32:00  12.1       42         0.78       101        8.8         lower
2023-06-20 09:33:00  11.7       48         0.82       99         8.4         higher
2023-06-20 09:34:00  10.9       55         0.85       102        8.9         higher
...
```

In this dataset, each row represents a specific point in time, and the columns correspond to different measurements or variables recorded at that timestamp. Let's discuss the meaning and purpose of the "Result" column.

The "Result" column represents the comparison between the current value in Column 2 and the previous value. It indicates whether the current value is higher or lower than the previous value. The "Result" column is determined based on the following conditions:

- If the value in Column 2 is higher than the previous value, the
  corresponding entry in the "Result" column is labeled as "higher".
- If the value in Column 2 is lower than the previous value, the
  corresponding entry in the "Result" column is labeled as "lower".
- For the first value in Column 2 (the earliest timestamp), there is no
  previous value to compare with, so the "Result" column contains a NaN
  (Not a Number) value or any suitable representation for missing
  values

I am seeking recommendations for packages that can effectively handle this task. Specifically, I would like to know if there are any recommended packages within Tensorflow or PyTorch that would be suitable for this prediction problem. Additionally, I would appreciate insights into the approach or methodology that could be employed to achieve accurate predictions.

Any suggestions, examples, or code snippets demonstrating the implementation using the recommended packages and approaches would be highly valuable. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to use a neural network for this task, when it is a simple comparison, `n[i] > n[i - 1]`?

This is some basic array manipulation. Here is a function that accomplishes your task:

```py
def classify_series(series):
    classifications = []
    classifications.append(np.nan)  # Set first element to nan
    
    for i in range(1, len(series)):
        if series[i] > series[i - 1]:
            classifications.append("higher")
        elif series[i] < series[i - 1]:
            classifications.append("lower")
        else:
            classifications.append("equal")    
                    
    return classifications
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> classify_series([10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10])
[nan, 'higher', 'higher', 'lower', 'lower', 'equal', 'higher', 'lower']
```

Alternatively if you care about speed, you can take advantage of NumPy arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

def classify_series(series):
    classifications = np.full(len(series), np.nan, dtype=object)

    mask_greater = series[1:] > series[:-1]
    mask_lower = series[1:] < series[:-1]

    classifications[1:][mask_greater] = "higher"
    classifications[1:][mask_lower] = "lower"
    classifications[1:][~mask_greater & ~mask_lower] = "equal"

    return classifications
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> classify_series(np.array([10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 10, 20, 10]))
array([nan, 'higher', 'higher', 'lower', 'lower', 'equal', 'higher',
       'lower'], dtype=object)
```

You can change the `dtype` to `<U6` to improve efficiency even more, however then `np.nan` will be string `'nan'`.

If you're wondering about accuracy, it is 100% when using this method.